# CiviCRM and PayPal Pro's Transparent Redirect

Tags: civicontribute, payment-processor, paypal, pci-compliance

We are looking into [PayPal Payments Pro](https://www.paypal-marketing.com/emarketing/partner/na/portal/payments_pro.html) for payment processing. PayPal mentions "Simplified PCI Compliance" as a benefit and explains that the client can use Transparent Redirect to help with PCI compliance.

The [Payflow Gateway Developer Guide and Reference explains the Transparent Redirect](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#pci-compliance-without-hosted-pages---transparent-redirect) this way:

> PayPal Payments Pro and Payflow Pro merchants who want PCI compliance
>   while maintaining full control over designing and hosting checkout
>   pages on their website can use Transparent Redirect. Transparent
>   Redirect posts payment details silently to the Gateway server, so this
>   sensitive information never goes through the merchant’s website.

Per Eileen in [CiviCON Denver- Adventures in Payment Processing: 360 View from around the Globe](https://youtu.be/BXs5_dPOEFI?t=10m19s), it sounds like there is a way to get Civi to allow for transparent redirect.  Per [this comment](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16573?focusedCommentId=74703&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-74703), it sounds like transparent redirect was being worked on for 4.7.

**How would one implement Transparent Redirect in CiviCRM for PayPal Pro?** Do the recent payment processing changes in 4.7 allow for it?

I've looked at [PayPal Website Payments Pro and Express Configuration](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#pci-compliance-without-hosted-pages---transparent-redirect), but didn't see anything in there.  I've checked the demo for 4.7 to see if there is a setting in there, but didn't see anything in the payment processor setup.

We use Drupal and are currently on Civi 4.6.6, but looking to upgrade to 4.7 within a month or so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So far there is some support for transparent redirect in the Omnipay extension but not in the core codebase, as it requires an extra form in the process.

It's likely that at some point Omnipay will ship with core - so developing it in this context is fine. However, although there is an Omnipay library for Paypal its not currently in the extension

Comment: So, to recap: with transparent redirect in the Omnipay extension, and with Paypal Pro in core, the two won't talk to each without intervention. PayPal does have support in Omnipay, just not in the Omnipay CiviCRM extension.  So, the way forward is to get the Paypal Omnipay library into the Omnipay CiviCRM extension?  Or is the way forward to pursue getting Omnipay in core?

Answer (score 0):

From brief research, these are adjustments to the form that displays the payment information. You would most likely need to override the core file, including the SILENTTRAN=TRUE request parameter.

I've no idea if it's already implemented or not on someone's machine, but a search for "SILENTTRAN" on the CiviCRM GitHub repo doesn't turn up anything.

If you want someone to custom develop this for you I'd be more than happy to take a closer look at it - please contact me at john@civifirst.com.

Comment: What file would I override?